# Proving the Bijectiveness of a Discrete Binomial Function (multivariable)

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, trees

I am looking for a way to prove that this function $(f: \mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N})$ is bijective
\begin{align*}
    f((x_1, \dots, x_k)) &=  2+ \sum^k_{i=1} \binom{x_{k-i+1} + i -2}{i}
\end{align*}
If conditioned by the fact that $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \dots \geq x_k$ (also $k, x_j \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $j$). I will add here a picture of the $k=4$ case so that you can visualize what I mean by this. (the function $f$ gives the ranking of the trees in the sequence. I already know the function works but I am unable to prove it.

[Sequence of 4-furcating trees using the Colijin-Plazzota ranking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ogJE.jpg)

---

I've tried induction but it doesn't seem to exactly work (this is my attempt at backwards induction, I got very confused in the end):
Let us prove this by backwards induction. Note that for our base case, when $x_k \ne y_k$ (and $x_1 = y+1, \dots, x_{k-1}=y_{k-1}$), the two expressions $2+ \sum^k_{i=1} \binom{x_{k-i+1} + i -2}{i}$ are identical, except for the term $i=1$ that yields
\begin{align*}
    \binom{x_k - 1}{1} &= x_k - 1\\
    &\ne y_k - 1\\
    &\ne \binom{y_k - 1}{1}
\end{align*}
Thus our base case holds and $f(x) \ne f(y)$. Now assume that $f(x) \ne f(y)$ for $x_j \ne y_j$ and that for any $x_i,y_i$ where $i < j$, $x_i = y_i$. Now let us prove that  for $x_{j-1} \ne y_{j-1}$ (and that for any $x_i,y_i$ where $i < j-1$, $x_i = y_i$), $f(x) \ne f(y)$.
\begin{align*}
    f((x_1, \dots, x_k)) &=  2+ \binom{x_{k} + 1 -2}{1} + \binom{x_{k-1} + 2 -2}{2} + \dots \binom{x_{k-k+1} + i -k}{k}
\end{align*}
$$=2+ \binom{x_{k} + 1 -2}{1} + \dots  + \binom{x_{j} + (k+1-j) -2}{(k+1-j)} + \binom{x_{j-1} + (k+2-j) -2}{(k+2-j)} + \dots  + \binom{x_{k-k+1} + i -k}{k}$$

Comment: Map from what set to what set? The $x_j$s are meant to be positive integers? I suspect this is Macaulay's "binomial expansion" theorem (see, e.g., Exercise 7 in https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/18s/mt1s.pdf ).

Comment: @darijgrinberg this is amazing and really helpful! I figured this was a somewhat known result but the fact someone already proved injectivity is really nice. Thank you so much!

Comment: Macaulay supposedly did it, but I've never seen a precise reference.